# Spring Security - Active Directory returns 49 - 775 (User account locked) for valid (unlocked) users

Tags: java, spring, active-directory, ldap

I ran into a complete mystery. I have a Spring-based web app, that authenticates users against Active Directory. On one and only one server (PROD, where else, right?), it fails to pull the user info:

> Caused by: javax.naming.AuthenticationException: [LDAP: error code 49
>   - 80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 775, v1db1\x00] at
>   com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtx.mapErrorCode(LdapCtx.java:3087)

It's clearly not an account issue although it looks like one. I use my own credentials and they work for the desktop login (SSO) as well as in all other instance of this app running in different environments. For what I can tell, Spring AD is also configured appropriately:

```
<bean id="authProvider" class="org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.ad.ActiveDirectoryLdapAuthenticationProvider">
<constructor-arg value="${ldap.domain}" />
<constructor-arg value="${ldap.providerUrl}" />
<constructor-arg value="${ldap.rootDn}" />
<property name="authoritiesMapper" ref="authMapper"/>
</bean>

<bean id="authMapper" class="ca.myapp.spring.UserContextMapper">
<property name="adminGroupsAsString" value="${ldap.adminGroups}"/>
<property name="userGroupsAsString" value="${ldap.userGroups}"/>
</bean>
```

So to me it looks like the issue is with that single box. Anyone seen this behavior in the past? Any help is greatly appreciated.

I even ended up building a VM using the identical ISO image from PROD, to verify if I can reproduce the error. It works like charm - I am able to login and there are no authentication exceptions... Looks like it's that one particular box (PROD), where I get the "user locked" error for valid (unlocked) users.

Here is the version info, if needed:
RHEL 6.3
Tomcat 6
Java 1.7.09
Spring Security 4.0.3.RELEASE

Answer (score 0):

Solution turned out to be very easy. It was not a technical issue, but a people issue. Before the deployment, the spring context in the WAR file was modified to point to the test version of Active Directory by an anonymous well-wisher. The properties file was the same, pointing to the prod AD, but context config XML itself was changed... Someone has a very good sense of humor....